# How do I translate to different languages Google Admob's template for the EU Consent policy?

Tags: admob

I have successfully implemented the template shown in this link (https://developers.google.com/admob/android/eu-consent#collect_consent) after following all the the steps of the Guideline to make the app comply with the EU Consent policy. But no matter which language the user has as preferred in his device, this template will always show in English.

Is there any way in which the developer can translate this template of the official documentation of Google Admob?